# I want to append the mentioned tag in all the div's which does not have class 'block'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to append the mentioned tag in all the div's which does not have class '**block**'

```
if( !($('td').hasClass('block')) ){
    $('.block').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).append('<small style="color:green">Available</small>');
    });
    $('.block').mouseout(function() {
       $('small').remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: What's your HTML? You say you want to append the 'mentioned tag' (where did you mention this?) to `<div>` elements without the 'block' class-name, but you're testing the `<td>` elements? Please show the relevant HTML (think "*[MCVE]*") and JavaScript/jQuery, clearly showing which elements should have further elements appended, and which should not. That way we have a better chance of answering your question usefully, and without having to make guesses. Please remember that we know nothing about your code, or intent, except what you tell us; telling us *more*, and *clearly* helps us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modified your code like this

```js
$('td').on('mouseenter', function(){
 if(!($(this).hasClass('block'))){
 $(this).append('<small style="color:green">Available</small>');
 $('td').mouseout(function() {
  $('small').remove();
 });
    }
});
```

```css
td { width:150px; height:100px; float:left;background:#666; }
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
 <td></td><td></td><td class="block"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:not()` selector to exclude all elements with the `block` class, like so:

```js
var myElement = $("<small class='smallMsg'>available</small>");
$('div:not(.block)').append(myElement);
```

```css
div { border:1px solid #000; margin: 1em; padding: 1em; }
.smallMsg { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
<div class="block">Aliquam similique, ad explicabo.</div>
<div>Voluptatem recusandae numquam, pariatur?</div>
<div class="block">Accusantium repellendus deleniti, animi.</div>
<div>Neque eum vitae amet.</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/hsjs3hjc/

P.S I would recommend to be more specific about your divs to avoid unexpected results, for example, capture all `divs` that are inside `#myGroup` container.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all `div`s that don't have the class `block` with the selector `div:not(.block)`. This would look something like this:

```js
$("div:not(.block)").each(function() {
    $(this).append('<small class="appearOnHover">Available</small>');
});
```

For the appearing and disappearing effect, I suggest to use CSS:

```css
.appearOnHover {
    display: none;
}
div:hover > .appearOnHover {
    display: inline;
    color: green;
}
```

Since I'm a pure js fan, here's also a solution with pure javascript:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll("div:not(.block)");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    var el = document.createElement("small");
    el.innerHTML = "Available";
    el.className = "appearOnHover";
    divs[i].appendChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you invert the conditions like this?

```
$('td').mouseover(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('block'))
    $(this).append('<small style="color:green">Available</small>');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('small').remove();
});
```

play around:
https://jsfiddle.net/sabkaraja/0o184u85/

Comment: It still doesn't work from your code.. anyways thanx.. I got it !! how to do

Comment: Dont understand why it doesnt work from my code. Check the jsfiddle link -- it works properly. Only the td classes with blocked will show available on mouseover